# Problem understanding directional derivates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

let $(\frac{\partial w}{\partial s})_u =\nabla w \cdot \frac{dr}{ds}= \nabla w \cdot \vec{u}$

I get why we let u be constant because we are intersecting some plane in the direction of u, but I don't understand why we let ds vary what is ds?

I think ds is $ds = \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$

Comment: I think is because we have to normalize the vector

Comment: Have you actually read your textbook where the directional derivative is defined and this formula is derived?

Comment: I saw a video I would love to see the derivation

Comment: Sometimes you should actually read true textbooks. If you watch my videos on multivariable calculus, they will not use this notation, but they are far more rigorous than the majority of calculus te tbooks.